# unexpected results using pdo AND OR

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am working on search form with multiple filters ..but having unexpected results
M doing it using PDO. and created query based on url...ursing if,for statements

Url:`lType=sale&gender=M|F&loc=can|india|asia`

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1=1 AND type like :ltype AND location IN (:loca0) OR location IN (:loca1) OR location IN (:loca2) AND gender IN (:gend0) OR gender IN (:gend1)
```

so from url we can understand that i want to get results where type=sale (and) gender=m(or)f and Loc=can(or)idnia(or)asia

but not getting results  as expected ..

Thanks...

**UPDATE**

As anwsred by `user876345` i tried to modify my loop to bind locations

```
if(isset($_GET['loc'])){        //locations
for($i=0;$i<count($aloc);$i++){
if($i<1 && count($aloc)==1) {$sqlsl .=" AND (location IN (:loca$i))";}
else if($i<1 && count($aloc)>1 && count($aloc)!="$i" ) {$sqlsl .=" AND (location IN (:loca$i)";}
else if($i>=1 && count($aloc)>1 && count($aloc)!="$i") {    $sqlsl .=" OR location IN (:loca$i)";}
else if($i>1 && count($aloc)>1 && count($aloc)==$i+1) { $sqlsl .=")";} 
$bind['loca' . $i] = $aloc[$i];
}
}
```

but this loop not adding `)` at end if theres more than 1 locations and output

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1=1 AND (location IN (:loca0) OR location IN (:loca1) OR location IN (:loca2)
```

Comment: ` SELECT * FROM table WHERE type= :ltype AND location IN(:loca0,:loca1,:loca2) AND gender IN(:gend0,:gend1)`

Comment: Did you bind your parameters correctly ?

Comment: y this question getting downvote huh!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closed the conditions in proper pair of `()`

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1=1 AND (type like :ltype) 
       AND (location IN (:loca0) OR location IN (:loca1) OR location IN (:loca2)) 
       AND (gender IN (:gend0) OR gender IN (:gend1))
```

Comment: Thanks..as i am binding parametrs using loops..m strucked in some part..plz check update

Answer (score 1):

Pair your or/and condition with proper bracket/grouping in where clause.

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1=1 
    AND type like :ltype 
    AND (location IN (:loca0) OR location IN (:loca1) OR location IN (:loca2) )
    AND (gender IN (:gend0) OR gender IN (:gend1))
```